# IFRAMES: event between contentWindow.beforeunload() & onload()

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to modify some `CSS` on a website that I have limited access to.  I've been allowed to create a page on the server, but can't modify other `PHP` generated pages on the site.

I'm exploring injecting `CSS` into an `iframe`.  I first hide the `iframe`, and then reveal it after my changes are made.

Unfortunately, the only time I know I have access to `iframe.contentWindow.document` is after the `iframe.onload()` event fires.  Most of the page is loaded asynchronously so what would have been 3-second wait to see content on the screen is now an agonizing 7-10 second wait while all external content is loaded, including social media content.

Is there any event that fire before `onload()` that would me know I have access to the new document?  I only want to inject a `stylesheet` into the head, I don't care if 90% of the `DOM` is "ready".

Comment: really, beforeunload is irrelevant as that's nothing to do with the "current page"

Comment: don't know if it's possible to add a `MutationObserver` on the `iframe.contentDocument` but that may be something that can help (wait for `head` to be added to the dom, then do your thing)

Comment: I understand I've just tried every Iframe related event I could find and onbeforeload, and onload are the only two i've seen work.  I'm suspecting its not possible but wanted to make sure before I abandoned the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the sort of thing you're after - but it may help

NOTE: I don't like this type of code generally, I originally thought I would use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - however, I found I had to do something like the above while waiting for the iframe's contentDocument to indicate that the content had started loading before I could attach the mutation observer - and then I'd miss the `head` element being attached half the time!

Firefox has a mozbrowserloadstart event on iframes - but that's just firefox, so not at all useful anywhere else

```
function limitedRetryWithDelay(count, delay, tester, cb) {
    var res = tester();
    if(res) {
        cb(res);
    } else {
        if (count > 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                limitedRetryWithDelay(count - 1, delay, tester, cb);
            }, delay);
        }
    }

}
// next 3 lines is just how I tested it - you'll need a reference to the iframe node instead for "tgt"
var tgt = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(tgt);
tgt.src = '/index.html?_=' + Math.random() + '_' + Math.random();
// end testing code

// try every 10ms for 5 seconds because (500 * 10 = 5000ms)
limitedRetryWithDelay(500, 10, function (e) {
    return tgt.contentDocument && tgt.contentDocument.location != 'about:blank' && tgt.contentDocument.head;
}, function(head) {
    console.log('head is', head);
});
```

By the way, you may not need to wait for `head` to be present before doing something with the document, you may well be able to just wait for `contentDocument`

```
limitedRetryWithDelay(500, 10, function (e) {
    return tgt.contentDocument && tgt.contentDocument.location != 'about:blank' && tgt.contentDocument;
}, function(doc) {
    console.log('document is', doc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'm working on testing this.  I don't like timeout code either.  Do you ever see this type of solution in production?  Am I nervous about deploying this any chance it could break under certain situations?

Comment: I have had to do something like this in production for Chrome - because for some reason the iframe onload event in Chrome does not behave the same as in Firefox - i.e. in some circumstances it never fires - not sure if it's still the case now, but I'm no longer involved with that particular code so I don't care :p